# How to root Gionee M5 mini

Tags: rooting

Good day,  please I want to root my Gionee M5 mini without swapping roms I.e changing the rom, please any solution?  I've used almost all rooting softwares both PC and phones... And what Is the oem feature?

Comment: Which version of Android your phone is running?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Mediatek device, powered by MT6580 chip, so rooting should not be difficult. Most one-click rooting softwares are able to do that.

You should try [KingRoot](https://kingroot.net/root-installation-via-windows-pc/) desktop version, worked for a similar phone weeks ago.